# What is this connection on ttgo t7?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, connector, esp32

Bord Name: **TTGO T7**

I have searched both in the [github page](https://github.com/LilyGO/TTGO-T7-Demo) and in the [lilygo site](http://www.lilygo.cn/prod_view.aspx?TypeId=50033&Id=978&FId=t3:50033:3) but I can't find what is the use of the connector highlighted in the picture: could someone with more experience help me on this?

Seems something power related but if you look carefully there are pin numbers printed on the strips of the connector. Moreover there is another connector for the battery on the back of the board.

With this board is very difficult to find something like a 'manual'.
[image: ttgo_t7]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pins 21 and 22 are the i2c pins. So I’d say that is a QWIIC connector or whatever the other suppliers call it. You can purchase various boards from Sparkfun et al that plug into that. I have a little oled module using that interface.

Comment: True! thank you